# Regular Expressions not resolved after using re_path in django urls

Tags: python, django, regex, django-urls

I have a problem with Django urls:

**main urls.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include, re_path, path

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    re_path(r'^', include('tutorials.urls')),
]
```

**tutorials/urls.py**

```
from django.urls import re_path
from tutorials import views

urlpatterns = [
    re_path(r'^api/tutorials$', views.tutorial_list),
    re_path(r'^api/tutorials/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)$', views.tutorial_detail),
    re_path(r'^api/tutorials/published$', views.tutorial_list_published)
]
```

when i go to check API via browser after `python manage.py runserver` i get:
[image]

Looks like regular expressions are not resolved? Any ideas?

Comment: You visit `/api`, not `/api/tutorials`...

Comment: api/tutorials give the same output

Answer (score 2):

You asked the "http://127.0.0.1:8080/api" URL.
Your urlpatterns does not contains any path which could match with this url.
I don't know where you want to go with this url, but if you add

```
path('api', views.tutorial_list),
```

In your urlpatterns list, you will go to tutorial_list view for example.

You don't need to use re_path for path without regular expression. just use path function.

Comment: But if i go /api/tutorials it gives me the same error. It seems like there is some issue with ^ sign

Comment: Yes the ^ means the beginning of string. In your case, you path start by slash (127.0.0.1:8000/api) so you cannot write your path with ^ i think
You have to write this path for include tutoriel pattern
*path('', include('tutorials.urls')),*